# JSONObject returns a non null value of "null" after instantiating with string

Tags: java, android, json

I need to download JSON and then store it in JSONObject.

I am using org.json.JSONArray.

Here's all the code in one place:

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test
{
    public static JSONObject getJSON()
    {
    try
    {
        URL uri = new URL("http://events.makeable.dk/api/getEvents");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            return null;
        }

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        if (inputStream != null)
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            try
            {
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            String json = buffer.toString();

            JSONObject jObject = null;
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(json);
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            int i = 1;
            return jObject;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Testing method

```
 @Test
    public void addition_isCorrect() throws Exception
    {
        JSONObject json = Test.getJSON();
        assertNotNull(json);
        assertTrue(json.length()>0);
    }
```

First assert passes, the second doesn't, cause length == 0.

And what I get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEvyW.png). A JSONObject object with value of string "null".

No exception is thrown. I wrote the contents of buffer to file and validated it, and it validates fine.

Another picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw9ug.png

Why is it acting like this?

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "baaa.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
}
```

Comment: I think you need a **breakpoint** after adding the value of that object. Try to add a dummy line before `return` like `Log.i("tag", "DUMMY");` and put a breakpoint on it.

Comment: Here `JSONObject` Class belongs to which library ?? is it `google.simple.json` or `apatche` ?? which one 

This really confused us because you have not mentioned the import statement.@LLL

Comment: Sorry, I will update the post. It's org.json.JSONArray;

Comment: @LLL Try to put `log` in the `exception` block.

Comment: It's not even throwing the exception, but i put print stack.

Comment: Use the web browser on pc, verify it returns the json, (just did here). Error code is 200 which is ok, and passed the check.. error is further down below ... put a breakpoint on exception block, exception is swallowed up which is a bad thing to do. Log it!

Comment: `json` is not valid json

Comment: I added printstacktrace on all exceptions. And as I said, I tried writing the buffer value to txt file and then validating the contents with no problem.

Comment: @skadoosh why no exception then? Also I wrote it to txt and validated it.

Comment: In actual fact, I think the string is getting confused when converted to json object, due to either encoding, there are embedded unicode in the string, for example, `\u2019`, and the backslashes are escaped.

Comment: @AxelH I added the breakpoint, but nothing is changing. http://i.imgur.com/ZGksRlv.png

Comment: ok.. post your `json` data

Comment: OP: Did you set the character encoding?

Comment: @skadoosh read my previous comment about using webbrowser to do a get on the url and use a online json parser. its valid. Think the problem is the encoding.

Comment: @t0mm13b no, all I'm doing is the code snippet I posted. Where and how do I use it.

Comment: @AxelH the value is a string "null" not null value.. in junit assertNotNull passes

Comment: `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));` tells it to use the unicode decoder.

Comment: the json value is not `null` there is value in the `jsonObject`

Comment: Post your whole code

Comment: The problem is elsewhere, debug it from beginning to end.

Comment: Last but obvious question, you do have internet permissions in the manifest?

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi updated to the whole code. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @t0mm13b Yes, but I'm not even using the android emulator here, just running it in the unit tests, and as I said before, I can download the json, wirte it to file and validate it in a json validator with no problems.

Comment: Wait, unit tests... why did you not tell us this after all this? You were mocking the set up right? You have set up a mock server?

Comment: @t0mm13b Don't even know how to do it, but what difference does it make? It's not a network issue.

Comment: Add `return new JSONObject("{ \"return\": \"Not good\" }");` at the very last line, instead of returning null. Does the test pass? InputStream is not null?

Comment: @t0mm13b doesn't pass. It's not null.

Comment: The return line next to int i = 1; is executed. So nothing else is returned and no exceptions are thrown.

Comment: You do understand why I asked you to try it out? Show us your gradle?

Comment: @t0mm13b sorry, I misunderstood. This is really weird. http://i.imgur.com/P03MiEZ.png adding gradle to OP

Comment: What is the value of `jObject` outside of catch block, put a breakpoint on the line `int i = 1;` and check. If its still null. How are you testing this, on the device? OR on the emulator.

Comment: Can you use toString in the unit test to print in the console. If the simple json given by t0mm13b doesn't parse, I start to doubt about your JSONObject ;) Not in the method, but in the unit testing, on the result.

Comment: @AxelH I am also doubting the JSONObject now, since like I show in the picture, even with initialising it with  t0mm13b code returns "null"  http://i.imgur.com/P03MiEZ.png

It does print "null"

Comment: Try to print the result of the method, I doubt the debugger for the moment ;) check the console. I never had any problem with JSONObject and we used it on huge files.

Comment: @AxelH http://i.imgur.com/sAWcCLN.png

Comment: Can you just create a getJsonTest returning the JSON from t0mm13b. Without inputstream or anything and see if the result is the same.

Comment: @AxelH well apparently my JSONObject is broken.. http://i.imgur.com/yX5xO0x.png sorry I cut in bad place. its failing at assertTrue

Comment: Hmm... try upgrading to a newer library, try downgrading from release candidate builds to a more stable version, `buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc3"` ?

Comment: **** look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402155/android-unit-test-not-mocked

Comment: Since you run it on unit tesing, this is not using the library from any device, the SDK doesn't provide the code, just a signature a I guess, a return "null" ;) Try to include the jar in the gradle to see the result.

Comment: @AxelH Good catch!

Comment: That's still painfull to find ...

Comment: jeez... oh google, why...

Comment: To many version to download, to many upgrade, need to use some stub to stay "lightweight"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are running your code with Junit, it running on the SDK on your computer. This SDK doesn't provide everything, some are just some skeleton class providing signature of method and documentation but not the code. So you can't execute directly.

You need to import the library to be able to run it on testing.

```
testCompile 'org.json:json:the_correct_version'
```

See the version here :

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

This is based on the answer on this post : [Android unit test not mocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402155/android-unit-test-not-mocked)

Comment: Current version is : 20160212

Comment: And everything is happy in OP's lala land... :D

Comment: And OP lived happily ever after. Fin.

Comment: The correct version for Android is : `org.json:json:20080701` otherwise you will have different behaviour in `getString()` for `null`. On Android it will return null, On earlier version it will throw an `Exception`

Comment: Can you give me some documentation on this Exception for post 2008 version ?

Answer (score 0):

First convert json string into JSONArray then used that JSONArray object for getting the each JSONObject

Comment: JSONArray is also "null" if I do new JSONArray(json)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try of this

```
String json = buffer.toString();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
JsonObject updatedJson = jsonObject.optJSONObject("json");
return updatedJson;
```

Comment: i tried his code and i am getting the json value in `jsonObject`

Answer (score -3):

Dear you first try to get only  json = buffer.toString();
tell me the value of json.

if your string json is null then problem in file reading code.

Comment: You can see from the image I posted that it's not null http://i.stack.imgur.com/DEvyW.png

Comment: Not an answer, in fact, pass that into [this](http://json.parser.online.fr/) it is indeed valid.