# Convert String to JsonObject in kotlin returns null

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin

**Edit Found Solution:**

**Found the error in my code. I'm running this on a unit test and Android doesn't use JSON objects on unit tests because it's part of android. That's why it was returning null.**

Question:

I'm tying to convert my String back to a JsonObject using JSONObject("string")

Here is a sample of my String:

```
{
  "sessions": [
    {
      "locations": [
        {
          "lat": "14.2294625",
          "lng": "121.1509005",
          "time": 1560262643000,
          "speed": 0,
          "speedLimit": 0
        },
        {
          "lat": "14.2294576",
          "lng": "121.1509498",
          "time": 1560262713000,
          "speed": 0,
          "speedLimit": 0
        },
        {
          "lat": "14.2294576",
          "lng": "121.1509498",
          "time": 1560262714000,
          "speed": 0,
          "speedLimit": 0
        }
      ],
      "name": "1.5645220491E12"
    }
  ]
}
```

Its returning null on my JsonObjects:

```
content = "the string above"

var obj = JSONObject(content.substring(content.indexOf("{"), content.lastIndexOf("}") + 1))
System.out.println("obj1: " + obj.toString())

obj = JSONObject(content)
System.out.println("obj1: " + obj.toString())

var obj1 = JSONArray(content)
System.out.println("obj1: " + obj1.toString())

obj1 = JSONArray(content.substring(content.indexOf("{"), content.lastIndexOf("}") + 1))
System.out.println("obj2: " + obj1.toString())
```

All the outputs of this are null. Any way to know what error happens so I can adjust my json string?

Comment: maybe it's better to create a pojo model and use Gson library? Or you don't have such opportunity?

Comment: Try using [Retroft](https://square.github.io/retrofit/), it is much faster and easier.

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii this is just a simple unit test reading from a local json text file. Yes that is possible but I want to know why this code is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are running your code with Junit, it running on the SDK on your computer. This SDK doesn't provide everything, some are just some skeleton class providing signature of method and documentation but not the code. So you can't execute directly.

Try to add the library in testing

```
testImplementation 'org.json:json:your_version'
```

See the version here :

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

This is based on the answer on this post: [JSONObject returns a non null value of "null" after instantiating with string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37389154/jsonobject-returns-a-non-null-value-of-null-after-instantiating-with-string)

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no need to `substring` your JSON string. Put it inside `JSONObject` and it will work fine.
2. If you need to get neasted objects use `getJSONObject` or `getJSONArray` methods
3. Show your `content` string in code (or how do you load it)

**Your edited code**

```
val content = "the string above"

var obj = JSONObject(content)
```

Comment: Already did that, you can see in my code I have tried many different ways to convert it to an object, all of them return null.

Comment: Show how you load your string

Comment: I tried this on a volley StringResponse and worked fine

Answer (score 1):

I run this funtion to parse your string and it's ok. Your string is valid. Can you specify how do you init `val content`

```
 fun parseJson() {
    var stringJson = "{\"sessions\": [{\"locations\": [{\"lat\": \"14.2294625\",\"lng\": \"121.1509005\",\"time\": 1560262643000,\"speed\": 0,\"speedLimit\": 0},{\"lat\": \"14.2294576\",\"lng\": \"121.1509498\",\"time\": 1560262713000,\"speed\": 0,\"speedLimit\": 0},{\"lat\": \"14.2294576\",\"lng\": \"121.1509498\",\"time\": 1560262714000,\"speed\": 0,\"speedLimit\": 0}],\"name\": \"1.5645220491E12\"}  ]}"

    var obj = JSONObject(stringJson)
    System.out.println("obj1: $obj")
    var sessionArray: JSONArray = obj.optJSONArray("sessions")
    System.out.println("obj1: $sessionArray")
    var firstObject = sessionArray[0]
    System.out.println("obj1: $firstObject")
}
```